# Git website deployment

Tags: git

I have now configured my git to deploy my website.
I have a master branch which is the live state of the website. If I push this to my bare repo the website is uploaded.
Then I have a develop branch where I can test everything. This will get live if I merge it with the live branch and then push it.

But I am still having a problem.
I have found 2 solutions for the website deploy with git.
The difference between the 2 solutions is only the hook that are used.
For the first solution it uses git pull to create my www root. This means that I need a repo as www root.
The second solutions uses git checkout -f where it dont have to be a repo.
I don´t know which one is better for my needs.

My problem is that it is possible that other users can add/change/delete a file on my webserver with a ftp client.
The problem is that nothing is commited using git. Now I need to get the changes in my master branch on my bare repo.
But how can I do that? I think if the www root is a repo I have to do a commit or something else first and then pull that to my bare repo.
Is this possible to do that if the www root isnt a repo? How can I do that automatically that I get the content of my www root in my master branch if I pull the master branch?

Answer (score 0):

I think the more standard way of doing it is the `git checkout -f` method ( or similar methods like `git archive` ) where your www is not a git repo but checked out from a bare repo using hooks when you push to it.

When you are using such a thing for deploy, then you must ensure that everyone commits to git ( and ideally you should have CI, tests etc) and push that to production. You cannot have people uploading to production through FTP etc and also have this mechanism in the side. It is just asking for trouble.

If you cannot prevent people from making such changes, then having the www root as a repo makes more sense as you can keep track of changes and push them to the bare repo. Even if it is not a repo, you can still have another repo setup on the server where you copy over the files from www root and commit them.

Comment: As I understand with checkout -f and archive I have to create everytime a new www root because there are are files transmitted and if some file was delete I it will not be delete on the www root if I only overwrite the files or am I wrong? I cant avoid from files being uploaded to with FTP. But how can I keep track of the changes automatically? I mean I want to pull from my workstation. this should tell my bare repo to fetch the current live website from my server. How can I do this if the www root is a repo and if it is not?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your scenario correctly, it might be better to not push from the web root to your bare repo and pull from that bare repo to your local machine. Wouldn't it be better to sync the files in your web root to your local repo (e.g. with rsync), handle all the git stuff on your local machine (diff, add, commit &c.) and push it to the bare repo which could in turn trigger a checkout in your web root again?

Comment: I think I have to do something similiar to this. My problem is that users can create files on the web root with ftp which should not be delete. But the files that I delete on my repo should than be delete on the web root. but maybe I am going to use git-ftp or I have to sync the files of my web root to my local before I can submit my changes to it.